How to Extract Part of Variable After Choice
from How-to: Extract part of...:
set "keys= ABCD"
echo %keys:~1,1%
echo %keys:~4,1%

When part of variable extracted after choice, don't worked except using call
@echo off
set "keys= ABCD"
:test
choice /c %keys%
::call echo %%keys:~%errorlevel%,1%%
echo %keys:~%errorlevel%,1%
goto :test

Why echo %keys:~%errorlevel%,1% don't worked?
or is my writing format wrong?

You can use a For /f loop to capture the literal keypress and use it directly.
@Echo off

  Echo([A] [B] [C] [D]
  Call:GetInput Option abcd
  If not errorlevel 1 Echo(You Pressed %Option%
  Pause
Goto:Eof

:GetInput <returnVar> <characters>
  Set "%~1=" 2> nul || Exit /b 1
  If "%~2" == "" Exit /B 1
  For /f "Delims=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%T in ("%~2") Do Exit /B 1
  For /f "Delims=" %%K in ('Choice /N /C:%~2')Do Set "%~1=%%K"
  Set "%~1" > nul 2>&1 || Goto:GetInput
Exit /b 0

|| is a conditional operator, code following it only executes if the preceeding command returned a non-0 errorlevel. The first usage of it ensures a return variable was provided to the function. The second usage tests to confirm definition of the variable - which won't occur in the case the user presses CTRL+C followed by n
Other tests confirm the presence of arg 2 for the character set and validates the characters provided are suitable for Choice
To do it using the errorlevel to index from the string, you need to remove the whitespace from the Keys variable like so, and use Delayed expansion to expand the variable like so.
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "keys= ABCD"
:test
choice /c %keys:~1%
Echo !keys:~%errorlevel%,1!
goto :test

Note, if the choice command was executed within a parenthesised codeblock such as an if statement of for commands do, you would need to use an additional for loop to expand the current errorlevel, IE:
  If 1==1 (
    choice /c %keys:~1%
    For /f "delims=" %%E in ("!Errorlevel!") Do Echo(!Keys:~%%E,1!
  )



Thanks. from my post, how to directly get part like echo %keys:~%errorlevel%,1%? Is it possible?

@Mr.Key7 answer updated.

So. Must using call or delayed on?
